# Не срабатывает скрипт после получения страницы $.get(...)

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, get

Используя функцию `$.get()` по стандартному примеру, не срабатывает скрипт, идущий после использования получаемого контента. Тоесть:

```
$.get('page.htm',function(data){
    $('#id').html(data);
    alert(0) //не срабатывает
})
```

Так же пробовал прописывать действие третьим аргументом, но всё так же безрезультатно.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: так а код вообще отрабатывает( первая строка обработчика )?

а вообще - *нужно больше кода*, в этом - ошибок нет

Comment: точка с запятой после алерта.

Comment: проверил в консоли хрома, все срабатывает.

Comment: Больше кода

Comment: @AlexWindHope, срабатывает.

@dajver, после алерта нет действий, а только закрывающие скобки, следовательно точки с запятой не нужно.

Comment: Посмотрел, в общем у вас ошибка в JavaScript коде, а именно - *_uBuildMenu is not defined*.

Каким образом у вас могла отработать первая строчка?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, в принцыпе, об этом и догадывался. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы загружал html страницы методом load.

И если использовать get, post без сервера, то эти методы и не сработают, нужно через сервер. Load кстати тоже, в фф только без сервера можно загрузить данные.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, метод `load` как миниум короче :)

Попробовав, понял, что проблема не в коде, а в странице. Попробовав загрузить простейший пример с практически пустой страницой, понял, что код рабочий. Но именно с нужной страницой сайта не получается. В чём тогда может быть проблема? Разве какой-то другой скрипт может препятствовать исполнению этого?

Вот ``[здесь](http://shopseek.ru/test.htm)`` не срабатывает.